# Electrostatic potential energy of two concentric spherical conductors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, energy, capacitance

Suppose that a small spherical conductor is placed inside a hollow spherical conductor. The inner conductor has a charge $+q$, which induces a charge $-q$ on the inner surface of the hollow conductor, which in turn induces a $+q$ charge on the outer surface of the hollow conductor. I want to calculate the total electrostatic potential energy of the system.

My observation is that the system can be seen as a capacitor with two spherical plates. My question is: is correct to assume that the total electrostatic potential energy of the system is equal to the energy stored between the two plates of the capacitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remembering that the energy is stored in the electric field then the energy is stored in the electric field between the plates **and** the electric field outside the larger conducting shell.

In effect you have two capacitors, a two spherical plate capacitor and a spherical shell with the other "plate" at infinity capacitor.

Comment: This is because the outer sphere isn't grounded, right? If it was grounded, there would be a single capacitor.

Comment: @Maury - Yes, if the outer sphere were grounded there would be no charge on the outer surface of the outer conducting shell.